# facebook discussion on my web page - how to make comments visible for everyone?

Tags: facebook, comments

I have facebook discussion on my web page and it works, but I'm unable to see comments of users that are not in my friend list. 
For administrative purposes, which are described here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ I've added between

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/>
```

with my facebook user id, but I am unable to find the administration settings or something like that. Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem, I can't find "visible to everyone", "has limited visibility" option in the Comment Moderation Tool. I'm wating for a answer to this question too...